# Importance of mass flow rate on the overall heat transfer coefficient

Tags: heat-transfer

As mass flow rate increases so does the heat coefficient. Is there a way to directly relate this? Is it because of the flow going from laminar to possibly turbulent also help increase heat transfer. This is an example based on a Shell and Tube heat exchanger.

Comment: Mass flow moves the heat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relation between heat transfer coefficient and mass flow rate could be easily related only in laminar flow, which will basically not occur in correctly designed heat exchanger. Heat transfer is strongly influenced by turbulence but also by other factors, so in the end, the difference in complexity of heat transfer in laminar vs. turbulent flow is greater than between the flows in these regimes.

For shell and tube heat exchangers, there are semi-empirical methods like the Kern's or the Bell-Delaware. You could also check out [Flow Stream Analysis](https://hedhme.com/content_map/?link_id=666&article_id=259).

Comment: What are the other factors? is it worth mentioning the volumetric flow rate increases to give a bigger mass flow rate.

Comment: Important factors are fluid properties like viscosity, density, heat capacity and conductivity and their dependence on temperature, then also geometry and of the channel (which is quite complex in case of shell and tube heat exchanger), materials (heat conductivity, but also capacity and density for transients) and surface quality.